# In Rails, how do I perform an intersect of two arrays based on a field in each object in the arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, intersection

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I have two arrays, (arr1 and arr2) that both contain my model objects.  Is there a way to do an intersection on both arrays if an object from arr1 has a field, “myfield1,” (which is a number) that matches an object in arr2?  Both arrays will have unique sets of objects.  Currently I have

```
arr1.each_with_index do |my_object, index|
    arr2.each_with_index do |my_object2, index|
        if my_object.myfield1 == my_object2.myfield1
            results.push(my_object)
        end
    end
end
```

but this strikes me as somewhat inefficient.  I figure there’s a simpler way to get the results I need but am not versed enough in Ruby to know how to do it.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26

Comment: Converting each array into a hash with the field as their keys e.g: `hash1 = arr1.each_with_object({}) { |x, hsh| hsh[x.field] = x };  hash2 = arr2.each_with_object({}) { |x, hsh| hsh[x.field] = x }` and do `(hash1.keys & hash2.keys).map { |x| hash1[x] || hash2[x] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an intersection of the values to find the common values, then select records that have the common values.

```
field_in_both = arr1.map(&:myfield1) & arr2.map(&:myfield1)
intersection = arr1.select{|obj| field_in_both.include? obj.myfield1} + 
               arr2.select{|obj| field_in_both.include? obj.myfield1}
```

I notice in your code, you're only storing records from arr1... if that's correct behaviour then you can simplify my answer

```
field_in_both = arr1.map(&:myfield1) & arr2.map(&:myfield1)
intersection = arr1.select{|obj| field_in_both.include? obj.myfield1}
```

Comment: I am not sure your solution will outperfom the solution in the question, given the cost of `Array#include?`. Converting each array into a hash with the field as their keys and using `(hash1.keys & hash2.keys).map { |x| hash1[x] || hash2[x] }` will perform better

Comment: @bjhaid I like your suggestion and if you write it up I'll vote it up.  However I think `hash1[x] || hash2[x]` will always return just `hash1[x]` since by definition of iintersection it will always exist.  That part might need to be re-analyzed.

Comment: you are correct either `hash1[x]` or `hash2[x]` should suffice in place of `hash1[x] || hash2[x]` depending on the object the OP is interested in

Comment: Yes, OP said the two arrays are "unique sets of objects" so presumably there's no object overlap, just a common value in an attribute. That's why I covered both cases in my answer... all objects from the two arrays with the overlaps, or just the arr1 object.  If it's both, I suppose your answer could be modified to `(hash1.keys & hash2.keys).map { |x| [hash1[x],  hash2[x]] }.flatten`  The other difference is whether mutiple objects in arr1 (or arr2) could have the same attribute value?  The hash method wouldn't support that as is.